# A Subversion client on my tablet Asus Transformer?

Tags: sync, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I am a developer, but I write some novels and short stories, and I use subversion to backup and synchronize texts files between PC. I want to read and write my text files on my Asus Transformer, but as far as I can see there is no subversion client for Android. I have only found Subdroid, but it is limited to history browsing, I can't get files and commit them.

I know Ubuntu is available for the Transformer, and I already use it on PC. But it's not my first choice for this tablet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just released an open source svn client that uses actual svn protocol... it is called OASVN (Open Android SVN) you can get it on the play market here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.valleytg.oasvn.android

Does svn checkout, update, commit, export, cleanup and revert. More to come soon.

More information and source are here: http://www.valleytg.com

Jira for requests: http://www.valleytg.com/jira

Answer (score 6):

It looks like there's been a little work porting SVNKit to Android (see [this](http://old.nabble.com/svnkit-on-the-Android-operating-systems---some-ideas-and-hints-td24786935.html)), but actual source code isn't sitting around for anyone to use yet.

It's a little bit incredibly gross, but you could try introducing another syncing setup.  Something like Dropbox to store and sync files on your phone, and then commit the changes when you get to a machine with an SVN client.  This is obviously less than ideal.